# Is it mandatory for some students to fail in an exam using relative grading?

Tags: grades, grading, instructor

I am seeing the relative grading structure of few of the institutions. The formula they follow for grading is as follows.

For a large batch of students:

1. they take the final marks of students
2. Calculate the mean marks
3. Calculate the standard deviation of marks
4. Then for those students whose marks are greater than mean + 1.5* standard deviation are assigned A+ ( the highest grades).
5. those students whose marks are less than mean - 1.5* standard deviation are assigned F( failed).

My question is if the distribution turns out to be **symmetric around mean (like Gaussian),** will it not be true that there must be some students that will fail mandatorily.

I may be wrong but I find this concept quite absurd and amusing. Can someone help me with this?
**I have many times seen in class having relative marking all the students to pass, how this is achieved or the distribution is not symmetric there?**

Comment: What if no student has a score less than 1.5 standard deviations below the mean?

Comment: @GoodDeeds If I say that none of the student has got less than 1.5 of standard deviation then I am saying that distribution is asymmetric. However, in a large class distribution should more or less follow Gaussian or for that sake if I take any symmetric distribution then suppose I got 10% students A+ grade is it possible then that no student will fail?

Comment: My experience, even with large classes, is a bimodal distribution... the students who get it and the students who don't.  In such a distribution, the mean is not really a useful measure of central tendency.

Comment: Possible duplicates or at least related questions: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/167023/ https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20063/ https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/160109/ https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/121991/

Comment: @Userhanu Not necessarily: every student getting the same mark also gives no students below -1.5sd. I also see no reason to expect the distribution to be anything like symmetrical. Comparing the data [here](https://analytics.ofqual.gov.uk/apps/GCSE/9to1/) and [here](https://filestore.aqa.org.uk/over/stat_pdf/AQA-GCSE-GDE-BDY-JUN-2019.PDF) (PDF) for 2019 (since 2020 exams didn't happen), many subjects look very asymmetrical.